# Identifying user from AWS Sagemaker Studio generated EFS storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-efs

When a sagemaker studio domain is created. An EFS storage is associated with the domain. As the assigned users log into Sagemaker studio, a corresponding home directory is created.

Using a separate EC2 instance, I mounted the EFS storage that was created to try to see whether is it possible to look at each of the individual home domains. I noticed that each of these home directories are shown in terms of numbers (e.g 200000, 200005). Is there a specific rule on how this folders are named? Is it possible to trace the folders back to a particular user or whether this is done by design?

(currently doing exploration on my personal aws account)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you [list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sagemaker/list-user-profiles.html) and [describe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sagemaker/describe-user-profile.html) the domain users, you'll get back the user's `HomeEfsFileSystemUid` value.
Here's a CLI example:

```
aws sagemaker describe-user-profile --domain-id d-lcn1vbt47yku --user-profile-name default-1588670743757
{
    ...
    "UserProfileName": "default-1588670743757",
    "HomeEfsFileSystemUid": "200005",
    ...
}
```